# Unity2D let's me edit three thing when i create a material

Tags: unity-game-engine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN47C.png)

When I created a Material it lets me edit Diffuse, Mask and Normal, which doesn't show up in my tutorial. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Under 'Shader' you have UniversalRenderPipeline -> 2D -> Sprite-lit-default, and this shader you can take Diffuse which is the main image, Mask which hides a part of the image and Normal Map which will fake depth with a normal map image. You can change the 'Shader' to 'Standard Shader' and that is likely what your tutorial is using.

Comment: Thank you so much!! sorry if my question was dumb

Comment: No problem we were all new sometime, feel free to mark as correct and upvote